# ffmpeg command not found but pip list shows ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, pip

I have been trying to install ffmpeg using the command
`pip install ffmpeg` and I am doing this in a server where we dont have sudo permissions. On writing ffmpeg I get ffmpeg: command not found. Then I checked with `pip list` and it showed ffmpeg. Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

`pip install ffmpeg` installs a [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg/) that doesn't have any executable scripts; it's for calling functions from Python code.

If you want to install `ffmpeg` program you need to run — what do you use, Ubuntu? — `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

The Python package requires the program anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to run `pip install ffmpeg-python` and not `pip install ffmpeg` or `pip install python-ffmpeg`. As @phd says that `pip install ffmpeg` will only install a Python package.

Comment: `ffmpeg` (program) must be installed anyway: https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python#installing-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

Try `conda install ffmpeg`. This will also work if you do not have sudo access. Pip installation might not work sometimes.

Comment: Hello, you could specify what conda is/does to help the OP. While you it is true you don't need sudo rights with conda, OP may not be using/wishing to use conda environments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. This worked with `Jupyter` docker container **without** sudo access.