# Python yt-dlp and ffmpeg error "merging of multiple formats but ffmpeg is not installed"

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python, yt-dlp

I am using the latest version of `yt-dlp` with Python 3.9.

I am trying to download a youtube video in mp4 format with outputname as the `youtubeid.mp4` and with best resolution not more than 4K.

This is my Python code:

```py
ytid = '4cDqaLxrt6Q'
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+ytid
output_filename = ytid+".mp4"
    
with YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestvideo[height<=?4K]+bestaudio/best', 'output': output_filename}) as ydl:
    ydl.download(url)`#TODO debug FFmpeg and check if outputname is ok
```

I expected to have an `.mp4` file in my current working directory.

Then I installed the latest version of `FFmpeg` from `ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl.zip` and put `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe` and `ffprobe.exe` in Scripts python folder (where `yt-dlp.exe` is). I also installed `ffmpeg` using `pip install`.

The `Traceback` is:

> [youtube] Extracting URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cDqaLxrt6Q
> [youtube] 4cDqaLxrt6Q: Downloading webpage
> [youtube] 4cDqaLxrt6Q: Downloading android player API JSON
> [youtube] 4cDqaLxrt6Q: Downloading MPD manifest
> [youtube] 4cDqaLxrt6Q: Downloading MPD manifest
> [info] 4cDqaLxrt6Q: Downloading 1 format(s): 243+251
> ERROR: You have requested merging of multiple formats but ffmpeg is not installed. Aborting due to --abort-on-error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\t\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\project\main.py", line 88, in 
> ydl.download(url)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3353, in download
> self.__download_wrapper(self.extract_info)(
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3328, in wrapper
> res = func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1486, in extract_info
> return self.__extract_info(url, self.get_info_extractor(key), download, extra_info, process)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1497, in wrapper
> return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1594, in __extract_info
> return self.process_ie_result(ie_result, download, extra_info)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1653, in process_ie_result
> ie_result = self.process_video_result(ie_result, download=download)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 2767, in process_video_result
> self.process_info(new_info)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 3189, in process_info
> self.report_error(f'{msg}. Aborting due to --abort-on-error')
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 1007, in report_error
> self.trouble(f'{self._format_err("ERROR:", self.Styles.ERROR)} {message}', *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yt_dlp\YoutubeDL.py", line 947, in trouble
> raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
>
> DownloadError: ERROR: You have requested merging of multiple formats but ffmpeg is not installed. Aborting due to --abort-on-error

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1. As a workaround, check your system path in Powershell, running: `$Env:Path`
   Put all three executables ff* in one of the listed paths.
2. Best way, put all three executables in a folder of your choice and then add that path in Windows env PATH. How to do that depends on your Windows version; check Settings, search in for environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `conda` as your Python package manager, you can install `ffmpeg` in the virtual environment.

Note that the `conda` method is different from the `pip` method you mentioned.

```bash
(base) C:\Users\user> conda install ffmpeg
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270671/22124527

---

> I have installed last release of FFmpeg from ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl.zip and put ffmpeg.exe , ffplay.exe and ffprobe.exe in Scripts python folder.

"Put `.exe` in the same python script folder" does not implies "add `.exe` in the **system path** that python can find".
You can try:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/exe/file/location')
```